# Parsing and Increment of IP Addresses

Tags: c#, string, parsing, text-files, ip-address

I have input text data like following:

```
AX  AMDBCEFG    103.12.96.0     103.12.98.255   
AX  AMDBDEFG    103.11.64.0     103.13.64.255   
AX  AMDBEEFG    103.14.24.0     103.14.24.255
```

The output I am looking for is a new text file:

```
AX  AMDBCEFG    103.12.96.0     103.12.96.255  
AX  AMDBCEFG    103.12.97.0     103.12.97.255 
AX  AMDBCEFG    103.12.98.0     103.12.98.255   
AX  AMDBDEFG    103.11.64.0     103.11.64.255 
AX  AMDBDEFG    103.12.64.0     103.12.64.255   
AX  AMDBDEFG    103.13.64.0     103.13.64.255
AX  AMDBEEFG    103.14.24.0     103.14.24.255
```

`First line` from the input incremented `3rd Octet` only i.e. `96 to 98`.
`Second line` from the input incremented `2nd Octet` only i.e. `11 to 13`.
`Third line` from the input `remains same`.

**What I have tried so far**:

I have treated IPs as string and then splitting on the basis of `.` which is quite tedious thing to do.

```
string sFile = "D:\\input.txt";
string sNewFilePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\\Output", Path.GetFileName(sFile));
string[] arrLines = File.ReadAllLines(sFile);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sNewFilePath))
{
    foreach (string sLine in arrLines)
    {
        string[] arrTab = sLine.Split('\t');
        string sIP1 = arrTab[2].Trim();
        string sIP2 = arrTab[3].Trim();

        string[] arrIP1 = sIP1.Split('.');
        string[] arrIP2 = sIP2.Split('.');

        int iOct1_IP1 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP1[1]);
        int iOct1_IP2 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP2[1]);

        int iOct2_IP1 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP1[2]);
        int iOct2_IP2 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP2[2]);

        int iOct1_Diff =  iOct1_IP2 - iOct1_IP1;
        int iOct2_Diff = iOct2_IP2 - iOct2_IP1;

        if (iOct1_Diff > 0)
        {
            //loop & increment
            //write lines to file
        }
        else if (iOct2_Diff > 0)
        {
            //loop & increment
            //write lines to file
        }
    }
}
```

Before proceeding further I figured out that I could use [System.Net.IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
System.Net.IPAddress ip1 = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(sIP1.Trim());
System.Net.IPAddress ip2 = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(sIP2.Trim());

if (ip1.Equal(ip2)) 
{
    //...
}
```

My question, is there any preferred way using above-mentioned class or any other technique to achieve this?

Sorry for lacking knowledge about the terms used for increment IP addresses.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to archieve? I don´t understand your question or what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Want an output file which shows, start and end range of IP addresses (As shown in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is alway use already existing parse/format method of BCL, like the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method of IPAddress class.

You can after use method [IPAddress.GetAddressBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) for get single parts of address

You can then increment the single parts of address, and create the new address

See demo for working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cjwlXk

this also work for range with different second and third part like 192.168.1.0 -> 192.169.14.0

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var fromIp = item.From.GetAddressBytes();
    var toIp = item.To.GetAddressBytes();

    Console.WriteLine("From {0} to {1}", item.From.ToString(), item.To.ToString());

    foreach (byte secondPart in Enumerable.Range(fromIp[1], toIp[1] - fromIp[1] + 1))
    {
        foreach (byte thirdPart in Enumerable.Range(fromIp[2], toIp[2] - fromIp[2] + 1))
        {
            var ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] {fromIp[0], secondPart, thirdPart, fromIp[3]});
            yield return string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{2}", item.C1, item.C2, ip.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Enrico for your answer. I think this is right way to parse IPs. Can you modify your code to get `255` at the end of every 2nd IP? I haven't tried it yet, only looked at the demo.

Comment: changed the demo, simply use ``var ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] {fromIp[0], secondPart, thirdPart, toIp[3]});`` with last parameter of constructor using the toIp address part

Comment: Ok. Yes I just figured it out. Last octet of every first IP is also showing 255. Anyways, thanks for excellent answer.

Comment: in the demo now, the first address end with .0, the second with .255 ( from original values )